# Why won't my Java while loop stop and let me program terminate?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

```
import java.util.*;

public class Investment 
{

    public static int years=0;
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter an integer representing the whole dollar value of your initial investment: $");
        int startBal=kbd.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter the whole number percentage, excluding the percent sign, of the interest rate on the investment.");
        int interestRate=kbd.nextInt()/100;
        int endBal=startBal*2;
        int currentBal=startBal;
        while (endBal>=currentBal)
        {
            currentBal=currentBal*interestRate+currentBal;
            years++;
        }
        System.out.println("It will take "+years+" years to double your investment.");
    }
}
```

The output I'm seeing is:

Please enter an integer representing the whole dollar value of your initial investment: $
10000
Please enter the whole number percentage, excluding the percent sign, of the interest rate on the investment.
5

The "10000" and "5" are my input. The program should be printing my final statement with the answer "15," but instead doesn't do anything, and doesn't terminate.

Comment: This is a good question.  Code is there.  Input, expected output, and actual output are all there.

Comment: Please don't edit in "solved" to your title.  Here in SO, you can "accept" exactly one answer that solved your problem by clicking the checkmark next to that answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
int interestRate=kbd.nextInt()/100;
```

Since `interestRate` is an `int`, it gets rounded down to zero.

So this line:

```
currentBal=currentBal*interestRate+currentBal;
```

resolves to:

```
=> currentBal=currentBal*0+currentBal;
=> currentBal=0+currentBal;
=> currentBal=currentBal;
```

So the value never increases, so will never reach double its initial value, so infinite loop.

You would have to replace the line with:

```
double interestRate=kbd.nextInt()/100.0;
```

Comment: @Squidicide No problem :) Instead of editing title as "Solved - ...", accept an answer, and it will appear different on the Questions page.

Answer (score 1):

Your **interestRate** is declared as an int so it will be set to 0.

You should declare all values as doubles, since we-re talking about money we want to be precise :)

Answer (score 1):

You have an `int` interest rate, which when divided by `100`, becomes `0`.  Make it a `double` and use the `double` literal `100.0` to divide, to force floating-point division.

```
double interestRate=kbd.nextInt()/100.0;
```

The `currentVal` variable will need to be a `double` also.

My output with the changes:

```
Please enter an integer representing the whole dollar value of your initial investment: $
10000
Please enter the whole number percentage, excluding the percent sign, of the interest rate on the investment.
5
It will take 15 years to double your investment.
```

This will let the program finish.  But normally [it's not a good idea to use a `double` to store money](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency).

Answer (score 0):

Your doing integer division 5/100 which = 0 remainder 5.  So in your calculation you are multiplying by 0 so your current balance will always be 0 and never reach end balance.  Try using a double for your interest rate rather than an integer.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (endBal>=currentBal)
{
    currentBal=currentBal*interestRate+currentBal;
    years++;
}
```

of course it never terminate, you are only incrementing years but the variables on the while are endBal and currentBal

Comment: However, the currentBal is being continuously modified while iterating, Isn't it ?  and infinite looping is because of the user dividing 5/100, which is always going to be 0, and hence the interestRate and as a consequence the currentBal also.